# Insert Table button in RichText

Tags: layout, ckeditor, containers, xpages, richtext

I am studying the Layout container pattern in the Mastering Xpages (a step by step  guide...) book.

The structure of my Xpage is I have a Left panel with navigation links to move from different views and then i have 1 link that will call create New document xpage.

The above layout is based on the tutorial (Chapter10.nsf).

The weird thing I experienced is on the Insert Table button in one of my rich text field in the Xpage where after I clicked the Insert Table button, the layout structure changed, the left panel with navigatin links disappeared and only the form and fields are displayed.

The behaviour is not consistent. Sometimes the Insert table button will work properly meaning the pop up window it calls will show but sometimes does not work, i.e will ruin the layout of the Xpage.

Please help what could be the cause why the button is not behaving properly and how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- use the OneUI Layout control from the Extlib (or the upgrade pack)
- Does the behavior change? If it works -> done